# Spring boot Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I want to put restriction on this  "/realtime/updates" Url  but If I request "/anyurl" it redirects me to Login page. I want to be redirected to login page only for "/realtime/updates".

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
   @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
   public class WebSecConfig1 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    }
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/realtime/updates").hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin();



    }
    @Autowired
    public void ConfigGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("abc").password("123").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change one snippet in the `protected void configure`method.
Try this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/realtime/updates").hasRole("USER")
        .and().formLogin().permitAll();
}
```

Comment: Please specify exactly what the change is, as this is unclear what part of the code needs changing

Comment: @Schipunov It doesnt restrict any url I want to restrict "/realtime/updates" but its not restricting

Comment: @Shchipunov still this doesn't restrict any url including "realtime/updates"

Comment: Added minor changes in the answer

Comment: @Schipunov  Now it restrict all requests and redirects to login page

Comment: @FarhanSheharyar Please try again with new changes

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your restrictions in configure method.Your method like below :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/realtime/updates/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/otherURL/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/login")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/index")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .failureUrl("/loginControl?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginControl?error=false")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/index")
                ;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was calling super.configure(http); inside configure method I removed that it worked.

```
 This is was previous code:

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      super.configure(http);


      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/realtime/updates")
     .hasRole("USER")
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .formLogin();
}
```

This is current code that worked:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/realtime/updates")
     .hasRole("USER")
     .anyRequest()
     .authenticated()
     .and()
     .formLogin();
}
```